# Set the template for the frontpage

Tags: theming, 8

How do I change the Drupal 8 frontpage template, so it doesn't use the regular page.html.twig template?

Comment: Hi! Welcome do DA. :) I took quite a few liberties with editing the question, I hope I still kept the core of it intact. Otherwise feel free to revert or edit again, but please try to keep the text short and to the point.
Regarding answering your question, I don't know, but I notice that the views module has a `views-view--frontpage.html.twig` file. Following that patterns, it's possible that the the correct template name would be `frontpage.html.twig`. You might want to try. Other templates in core are named with a - separating their name from `page`, so perhaps `front-page.html.twig`?

Comment: I added all those files to my templates folder in my theme and still it shows the page.html.twig instead of those i cleared the cache too before reloading the page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Enable `twig_debug`](https://www.drupal.org/node/2358785) and you will see HTML comments surrounding the output that tell you what template suggestions are available. In this case you will get output like:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'page' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * page--front.html.twig
   * page--node.html.twig
   x page.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/page.html.twig' -->
```

Naming your template **page--front.html.twig** will use that template for only the homepage.

Comment: how does this work with subfolders? E.g. having a folder `page` in my `templates` directory.

Comment: @ferdynator it works just fine, you can add subfolders to organize your templates.

Comment: This won't be picked up until you clear your caches, of course (said the newbie)!